# Find all the factors of a given natural number, N

Tags: python, factors

I was asked this question in an interview:

> Find all the factors of a given natural number, N
>
> 1 <= N <= 10**10
>
> Example:
>
> N = 6 => 1, 2, 3, 6
>
> N = 60 => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60

I wrote following code,but got an feedback that complexity could be improved.

> How to optimise following code?

```
import math
def get_all_factors(n):
    ans = [1]
    if n==1:
        return ans
    factors = [False] * n
    for i in xrange(2,int(math.sqrt(n))):
        if not factors[i]:
            if n%i == 0:
                factors[i] = True
                factors[n/i] = True


    for i, is_factor in enumerate(factors[1:], 1):
        if is_factor:
            ans.append(i)
    ans.append(n)
    return ans        
    
ans = get_all_factors(60)
print [x for x in ans]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to keep an intermediate list here, just add all the divisors to a `set`:

```
from math import sqrt

def get_all_factors(n):
    divisors = set()
    for i in xrange(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divisors.add(i)
            divisors.add(n / i)
    return divisors

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_all_factors(60)
```

I also added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to allow importing this function from another script.

Note that there is no requirement for the output to be a sorted list in the problem statement you posted. If there is, you can just call `sorted` on the output of this.

As @kyrill mentioned in the comments, you could also make this a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

def get_all_factors(n):
    sqrt_n = sqrt(n)
    for i in xrange(1, int(ceil(sqrt_n))):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
            yield n / i
    if sqrt_n % 1 == 0:
        yield int(sqrt_n)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm is a bit shorter, doesn't need the `math` module (it uses `/` and `//` divisions instead) or any other module, and uses fewer `if` statements.

```
def get_all_factors(n):
    factor_list = []
    test_i = 1
    upper_limit = n       # consistent with n/test_i below when test_i = 1
    while test_i <= upper_limit:
        if n % test_i == 0:
            factor_list.append(test_i)
            factor_list.append(n//test_i)
        test_i += 1
        upper_limit = n/test_i
    return list(set(factor_list))   # remove duplicates and sort (e.g. dup 3 when n is 9)

print(get_all_factors(60))

#--> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60]
```

It works by testing numbers sequentially (`test_i` iterating from 1) and also by shortening the maximum possible factor (variable `upper_limit`) using the division result after each `test_i`. For more detail in how it works, just run it in debug mode and follow the evolution of variables and lists.

Note: Runs fine in Python3.  Minor `float` and `int` conversions needed to make it run in Python2 due to difference of `/` behavior.